# Chrome extension quit when onclick on file input

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

When i click on input type file :

```
<input type="file" class="filestyle" data-size="sm" data-buttonText="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Choisir une image" data-buttonBefore="true" data-disabled="false">
```

my html5 chrome extension quit and i can't add if to my form. How to prevent this behavior ?

Comment: You're going to have to provide more information. Don't even know where to start trying to help.

Comment: my chrome extension : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/zombiereport/nmojhgiclaimobhpljphbfgmabfmncin , on web : http://1ffa3ba638.url-de-test.ws/zombieReport/partials/popup.html